# changing style of NSIS link on hovered

Tags: colors, installation, hover, hyperlink, nsis

I have a link in my NSIS installer page and I'm trying to change its style (color). The link is declared in my .ini page like this:

> [Field 8] 
>     Type=Link 
>     Left=14   
>     Top=18    
>     Right=206 
>     Bottom=28 
>     Text=go to google... 
>     State=https://google.com/

then in the .nsh file i change its style calling:

> ReadIniStr $1 "${TEMP}\browse.ini" "Field 8" "HWND"   
>    SendMessage  $1 ${WM_SETFONT} $7 0  
>    SetCtlColors $1 0x000000 transparent

It does change the link's style but when i hover it, it goes back to its old style and changes back on refresh (when i drag a window over or press a button that will refresh the field) 
The default style looks like a button and i want it to look like an underlined label.
I've also tried to make it label and link it with Linker::link but changing the page skin with NSIS_SkinCrafter_Plugin::skin makes it disappear and i can't bring it back.

Can you please suggest a solution to my problem? I just want a blue underlined text that when hovered opens a webpage in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Try [Linker](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Linker_plug-in) plugin it can change a label into a link.

```
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $0 $0 1006
Linker::link /NOUNLOAD $0 "http://www.google.com/"
```

Comment: I already tried this. As I was saying in the description the problem with linker is that after changing the window skin my label disappears and doesn't appear again even if I refresh the label or I set all its properties again (text, color, visibility, etc)